# G+ iOS app: mentioning doesn't work

Tags: ipad, google

I'm using the G+ app on my iPad 2 (6.1). Whenever I try to mention people in comments and type "+", the name doesn't come up (as it does in the android app) so I can select it. Even when I type the full name and send the comment, it stays black like the rest of the text and doesn't convert to a link (blue).

Anybody else has this issue? Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems it was a bug that is solved in the new version.

Comment: Thansk for reporting back on this.